# How to pre-populate email address in combined siginsignup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

This is in reference to custom policy signupsignin user journey.  I have a self-asserted orchestration step that collects users email address before the combined signupsignin orchestration step.  I'm wanting to populate the email address in the signupsignin step but can't get it to work.

Orchestration Steps

```
  <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.selfasserted.email">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-CollectEmailAddress-NoError" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!--calls Azure function GetEmailDomain to get user domain -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="EmailDomainExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-API-GetEmailDomain" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>emailDomain</Value>
          <Value>ourdomain.com</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="RushEnterprisesExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the **email** claim is defined as an output claim from the **SelfAsserted-CollectEmailAddress** technical profile, then it must also be defined as an input claim to the **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** technical profile, so that the sign-in name field is pre-filled with it:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInName" />
  </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: I got error while trying above code. 'Too many values were encountered for key \"signInName\" in the TryGetValue method which can only return a single value. Please use TryGetValues method instead.'  Output claim of previous profile <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />

Answer (score 0):

Using PartnerClaimType seems to be a simple solution. But it did not work for me. I ended up using CopyClaimIfPredicateMatch transformation to copy from inputUserName to signInName, where the inputUserName is the output claim of the first orchestration step, and signInName is the input and output claim of SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email technical profile, for the second step. My experience in this area tells me that many of the behaviors of the claim signInName are not overridable, for example, set with a partner claim, or make it read-only.